# Get the inviter

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have code and I have checked about everything can i check about it.

So my code is get inviter by member and i found problem with it.

- What i did try:

First thing I add client#ready and loop all guilds & guild#fetchInvites then insert it in JSON

```
 json[ invite.code ] = invite.uses;
```

as you see, the key is the invite code, and the value is invite uses.

then I've add client#guildMemberAdd and guild#fetchInvites then I checked which invite has been changed ( on uses ) and consider the member to inviter.

- What happens:

After i have checked about everything, i found the problem ..

and the problem was in the difference of the current Invite#uses and the past of Invite#uses..
There no difference between those..

**CODE**:

```
module.exports.start = function ( ) { // executes when client is ready
    this.client.guilds.forEach( ( g ) => { 
        g.getInvites().then( ( i ) => {
            i.forEach( ( invite ) => {
                json[ invite.code ] = invite.uses;
            });
        });
    });
}

module.exports.getInviter = function ( member, callback ){ // executes when member join
    var inviter = false;
    member.guild.getInvites( ).then ( ( i ) => {
        i.forEach( ( invite ) => {
            if( invite.uses > json[ invite.code ] ){
                if( inviter == false ) {
                    callback(invite.inviter);
                    inviter = true;
                }
            }
            json[ invite.code ] = invite.uses;
        });
    });
    if( inviter == false ) {
        return callback(member.user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I did, anyways discord will add way to get inviter more easily.